# tap working throught layer bootstrap iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

I need help regarding mobile website on iPhone. I have implemented slide panel jquery plugin with bootstrap. The left-slide panel contains category links, positioned absolutely below the homepage. When I click the navigation button to open the slide-panel opens but the link below in slide-panel also get triggered. As a result page redirects to link after opening the slide-panel. Seeking for help...

Thanks